# Loop JSON requests to backend (REST API)

Tags: ios, swift, request, alamofire, swifty-json

I am sending request to the backend (REST API). My task: If the JSON response does not come in the required format, or returns an error, then start the request cycle - 3 attempts, and if these three attempts fail, then exit, else go next (HomePage)

Here is code:

```
func checkUsers(){
    
let headers: HTTPHeaders = ["Content-Type" : "application/json"]
NetworkManager.sharedInstance.manager.request("https://restapi.com/user",
    

                   
                   method: .get,
                   parameters: nil,
                   encoding: JSONEncoding.default,
                   headers: headers).responseJSON { (response) -> Void in

switch response.result {
    case .success(let value):
    let response = JSON(value)

    print("JSON Response: \(response)")

    if response["operation"].stringValue == "loginerror" {
        print("Error")
        
        self.showNotRegisteredScreen()
        
    } else {

    usersFIO = response["userName"].stringValue
    
    self.didFinishLogin()
}

case .failure(let error):
    print("fail to fecth data",error)

    self.showErrorScreen()
}
}
```

Please tell me how to start a request cycle in which to specify three attempts

P.S.: Using Alamofire and SwiftyJson pods

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/AdvancedUsage.md#adapting-and-retrying-requests-with-requestinterceptor ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me with Alamofire 5

```
lazy var manager: Alamofire.Session = {
            let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
            
            let retryPolicy = RetryPolicy(retryLimit: 3)
            let interceptor = Interceptor(retriers: [retryPolicy])
            
            let manager = Alamofire.Session(configuration: configuration, interceptor: interceptor, serverTrustManager: serverTrustManager, eventMonitors: [CertificateAuthAdapter()])
            return manager
        }()
```